display different text for html select option than label
Sorry if the title is confusing, but basically I have a react component that renders a select dropdown with a bunch of options. I want to display the options in the dropdown normally, but once selected, I want the selected value to be something else compared to its label.
It's easier to understand when mapping through an array called options which creates the options:
let's say we have an array called options with on object inside:
const options = [{name: "John Doe", value: "john", displayName: "John"}]

<select value={value}>
    {options.map(({ name, value, }, i) => (
        <option key={i} value={value}>
            // when the dropdown is open this should display name, but when we select it and the dropdown closes, we want to see the displayName instead
            {name}
        </option>
    ))}
</select>

Currently when clicking on the one option in the dropdown, there will be no difference between the option when the dropdown is open vs close.
Is there a way to set the selected option to look different when the dropdown is closed vs when it's open? I've seen some similar questions, but none that involved react but using standard html so all the js was jquery.

I'm not following. Are you saying you want to update the value attribute of the select based on the selected option? Can you provide a concrete example with real values, both before and after a selection is made?

updated question

It's probably a bad idea to do this; it might be confusing to users if the option they are selecting does not match the option that appears. If you must implement it this answer seems to have a suggestion

Here you go.
The workaround here is to hardcode the value of select and make the first option hidden which means the first option will not be displayed in the dropdown but it will be only displayed in select tag.
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const options = [{name: "John Doe", value: "john", displayName: "John"}, {name: "M Mudassar", value: "mudassar", displayName: "Mudassar"}]

  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null);

  const handleSelectChange = (e) => {
    const selectedOption = e.target.selectedOptions[0];
    const selectedData = JSON.parse(selectedOption.dataset.obj);
    setSelectedValue(selectedData);
  }

  return (
    <select value={'constant'} onChange={handleSelectChange}>
      <option value={'constant'} hidden>{selectedValue?.displayName ?? 'Please Select'}</option>
      {options.map((option, i) => (
          <option key={i} value={option?.value} data-obj={JSON.stringify(option)}>
              {option?.name}
          </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}

